# Number of permutations $a_1,a_2, \ldots,a_n$ of the sequence $1, 2, \ldots, n$ satisfying $a_1\leq 2a_2 \leq 3a_3 \leq \cdots \leq na_n.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations

How would you start solving,

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Find the number of permutations $a_1,a_2, \ldots,a_n$ of the sequence $1, 2, \ldots, n$ satisfying:
$$a_1\leq 2a_2 \leq 3a_3 \leq \cdots \leq na_n.$$

Comment: I'd start by trying to get a feel for what these permutations are like by finding the solutions for some small values of $n$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 4):

I’d think about where I can put the $1$, then where I can put the $2$, then where I can put the $3$, $\ldots$

Answer (score 2):

We first show that no number can be more than $2$ places above (to the right of) its initial position.

- If $1$ is at $a_3$ or right, the number immediately to its left would have to be $1$ too, which is prohibited.
- If $2$ is at $a_4$ or right, because $1$ is limited to $a_1$ and $a_2$, the number immediately to $2$'s left has to be $2$ as well, which is prohibited, and so on.

By similar logic we can also show that no number is more than $2$ places *left* of its initial position, so _all admissible permutations have $|a_n-n|\le1$. It is then easily seen that the inversions making up such permutations must be disjoint and operate on adjacent numbers, so the number of admissible permutations equals the number of tilings of a $1×n$ rectangle by dominos and monominos, i.e. the Fibonacci number $F_{n-1}$ (with $F_0=0,F_1=1$).

Comment: The question was how you'd **start** solving it ;-)